# How to return a service function as an observable in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, observable, angular7, angular-observable

I have this service.ts code:

```
export class BasicOperationService {

  constructor() { }

  delete(service: any, object: any, data: any): Observable<any> {
    const id = this.getId(object);
    let index: number;

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if ( data[i].id === id) {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
    }

    return service.delete(id).subscribe(result => {
        data.splice(index, 1);
        return data;
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        return data;
      });
  }
}
```

And I have this component.ts:

```
delete(object: any, id: number) {
  this.loadingId = id;

  this.basicOperation.delete(this.photoalbumService, object, this.content.data)
    .subscribe(result => {
      this.content.data = result;
      this.loadingId = 0;
    });
}
```

And now I get this error message:

```
TypeError: this.basicOperation.delete(...).subscribe is not a function
```

How can I return from BasicOperationService's delete() method as an observable?

Comment: you should return `service.delete(id).pipe(...)` in service, where in pipe you can clean up your data. calling subscribe returns a subscription.

Comment: @netdjw, NOT subscribe in service (really it's a bad idea). You have a service and want to return a observable, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can serve data as observable using Rxjs "of", e.g.

```
return of({id:1,data:"hello word})
```

But, in your case, you must use switchMap, because you must wait to service.delete finish.

```
delete(service: any, object: any, data: any): Observable<any> {
    const id = this.getId(object);
    let index: number;

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if ( data[i].id === id) {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
    }

    return service.delete(id).pipe(
       //we don't return the result of delete, else "data.splice"
       switchMap(result =>{
           data.splice(index,1);
           return of(data);
       }))
  }
```

Then you subscribe in the component

**Update** as IngoBürk say in his comments, in this case NOT use switchMap, just you can use map.

```
delete(service: any, object: any, data: any): Observable<any> {
    ...
    return service.delete(id).pipe(
       map((result)=>{
           data.splice(index,1);
           return data;
       }))
  }
```

"map" transform the result and the "return" must be an object. "switchMap" is util if you want to return a different observable -this is because in swithmap you must return an observable-

Comment: switchMap makes no sense here, splice doesn't return an observable.

Comment: `.pipe(map( ... ))` combination get the right result as suggested by @ABOS in a question comment, thanks!

Comment: @IngoBürk, you're correct. must be return of(data), Just correct in the code, thanks for the advise

Comment: @IngoBürk, don't take care about the pointless, thanks for force me improve my answer,

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but you perhaps you should

```
return service.delete(id);
```

and not subscribe.

Then, subscribe only in the the component that consumes the service.

Comment: Technically the `splice()` can be done in an operator such as `map()` to avoid needing to do it in the consuming component.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky That's true, you could chain a side-effect onto the return statement.

Comment: @KeenanDiggs, service.delete(id) return a service, but you have not the data. you have nothing